# White lines problem texture bake; render engine

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine, baking, uv-image-editor

I have a 3d scan that I'm baking onto a lower poly model inside the blender render engine. The baked image result shows some white lines that correspond with the uv islands of the UV map of the 3d scan. Anyone know how to get rid of these?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found it out. Turns out it solves it when you uncheck the box use alpha in the texture panel.